# TIdTcpClient thread stops responding after some time

Tags: delphi, indy

After some time my client thread stops receiving/sending commands from/to `TIdTcpServer`.
Here is the client side thread I copied from an example from Remy:

Tested locally and it doesn't happen, only on a running environment the error occurs...

```
type
  TDataEvent = procedure(const LBuffer: TIdBytes) of object;

  TReadingThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FClient : TIdTCPClient;
    FData   : TIdBytes;
    FOnData : TDataEvent;
    procedure DataReceived;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient); reintroduce;
    property OnData: TDataEvent read FOnData write FOnData;
  end;

constructor TReadingThread.Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FClient := AClient;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Form1.Cliente.IOHandler.ReadBytes(FData, szProtocol, False);

    if (FData <> nil) and Assigned(FOnData) then Synchronize(DataReceived);
  end;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.DataReceived;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnData) then FOnData(FData);
end;

procedure TForm1.DataReceived(const LBuffer: TIdBytes);
type
  PTBytes   = ^TBytes;
  PTIdBytes = ^TIdBytes;
var
  LDataSize   : Integer;
  LProtocol   : TProtocol;

  LBuffer2    : TBytes;
  LProtocol2  : TProtocol;
begin
  LProtocol := BytesToProtocol(PTBytes(@LBuffer)^);

  case LProtocol.Command of
    cmdHWID:
    begin
      HWID := LProtocol.Sender.HWID;
     end;

    cmdPing:
    begin
      InitProtocol(LProtocol2);
      LProtocol2.Command      := cmdPing;
      LProtocol2.Sender.PBack := GetTickCount;
      LBuffer2                := ProtocolToBytes(LProtocol2);
      Form1.Cliente.IOHandler.Write(PTIdBytes(@LBuffer2)^);
      ClearBuffer(LBuffer2);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

For a while all works perfectly, but after some time, the client side stops receiving/sending. The connection to the server is seems to be still open.

function to find connection by ip:

```
list := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
      try
        for i := 0 to list.Count - 1 do
        begin
          ctx := TIdContext(list[i]);
          if ctx.Binding.PeerIP = Edit9.Text then
          begin
            TLog.AddMsg('IP FOUND');

            Achou := True;
            Cliente := TClientContext(ctx);

            SerialCn  := Cliente.Client.HWID;
            IpCn      := Cliente.Client.IP;

            break;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
      end;
```

Comment: You did not specify whether the thread has stopped because it has been terminated, or is just blocked on `ReadBytes()`, `Write()`, or `Synchronize()`. Please debug your code to find that out. Also, why are you synchronizing `TForm1.DataReceived()` anyway? There is nothing in it that needs to be synced with the UI thread, except maybe the `HWID` assignment, which you could use `TIdThreadSafeString` instead of `Synchornize()` for that.

Comment: i found the problem, isn't client side who stop work. it's TIdTcpServer who lose the connection to TIdTcpClient. You know why it can happen?

Comment: It could happen for any number of reasons. Try using the server's `OnException` event to see if an unexpected exception is terminating the connection thread. Closing the connection gracefully on the server side should cause the `IOHandler` to raise an exception on the client side immeidately.  Otherwise, if the connection is lost abnormally, it might take awhile for the client to see it.  Try setting the client's `ReadTimeout` to compensate for that.

Comment: Checked onexception, Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer. only generate on onexception event when i search the ip using (i updated the topic with function who i use to found the connection by ip). the strange behavior is, after generated the exception on TIdTcpServer, TIdTcpCLient connection still stabilished.

Comment: That's strange, appear be TIdTcpServer drop TIdTcpClient after send some commands generating the error 10054

Comment: I'm not familiar with what TProtocol is, but knowing about TCP, it may be that you need to initiate pings yourself at regular intervals when there's no data going over the line, and not only respond to pings from your client as your example does.

Comment: solved problems like you said, send a ping to server every x time.